# How to pass windows value to child window using PHP and javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a search page written in PHP. If there are results found, instead of displaying the list in the same page, I would like to display the results in the pop up window. I only come as far as opening a new pop up window but I don't know how to pass the values.

```
if($results != 0){
  //call the pop up window
}
else{
  //display message here. 
}
```

Thanks. I have search some  possible duplicates about these question, but the results did not work for me.

Comment: Are you trying to open clientside window with PHP?

Comment: there are hundred of 'pop up window' scripts avalable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($results != 0)
{
    //call the pop up window
    ?>
    <script>
    var win = window.open("","_blank");
    win.document.open();
    win.document.write(<?php /*resulting HTML of your search results*/?>);
    win.document.close();
    </script>
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    <script>
    alert("no results");
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Something like that?

Comment: it's not the good way to code. I think you should assign the result value for a javascript variable, after that, you check the javascript variable value for display the popup.

Comment: That would work too, but there's no harm in jumping between php and html. The document.write(<?php?>) part is questionable though.

Comment: OK. I think it will work. but It's difficult when you maintenance you code. That the reason why to day everybody prefer PHP MVC framework than use standard php.